# how to remove auto key in grouping multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

**I have few data query as below**

> Workspace data structure

```
$workspace = array(
    array(
        "ticket_category_id" => "825",
        "ticket_category_name" => " Category 1",
        "ticket_category_order" => "1",
        "ticket_list" => array()),
    array(
        "ticket_category_id" => "826",
        "ticket_category_name" => "testing category for intermediate hub",
        "ticket_category_order" => "1",
        "ticket_list" => array()),
    array(
        "ticket_category_id" => "827",
        "ticket_category_name" => "testing category for intermediate hub",
        "ticket_category_order" => "1",
        "ticket_list" => array()),
    array(
        "ticket_category_id" => "836",
        "ticket_category_name" => "testing category for intermediate hub",
        "ticket_category_order" => "1",
        "ticket_list" => array()),
);
```

> Ticket data structure

```
$ticket = array(array(
    "ticket_id" => "1",
    "ticket_title" => "Fun",
    "ticket_order" => "1",
    "category_id" => "826",
    "due_date" => "2019-04-14 06:32:37",
    "due_timestamp" => "1555194757",
    "created_date" => "2018-01-31 07:11:10",
    "created_timestamp" => "1517353870",
    "edited_date" => "2018-04-10 02:40:54",
    "edited_timestamp"=> "1523299254",
    "updated_date"=> "2018-04-10 02:40:54",
    "updated_timestamp"=> "1523299254",
    "is_complete"=> "0",
    "total_comment"=> "0",
    "total_attachment"=> "0",
    "total_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "total_completed_checklist_items" => "0",
    "label" => array(),
    "people"=> array(),
    "module_role"=> "author"
),array(
    "ticket_id"=> "2",
    "ticket_title"=> "out摸索",
    "ticket_order"=> "1",
    "category_id"=> "826",
    "due_date"=> "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "due_timestamp"=> "0",
    "created_date"=> "2018-01-31 09:24:24",
    "created_timestamp"=> "1517361864",
    "edited_date"=> "2018-01-31 09:24:31",
    "edited_timestamp"=> "1517361871",
    "updated_date"=> "2018-01-31 09:24:31",
    "updated_timestamp"=> "1517361871",
    "is_complete"=> "0",
    "total_comment"=> "0",
    "total_attachment"=> "0",
    "total_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "total_completed_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "label"=> array(),
    "people"=> array(),
    "module_role"=> "author"
),array(
    "ticket_id" => "2804",
    "ticket_title" => "asdas",
    "ticket_order" => "6",
    "category_id" => "827",
    "due_date" => "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "due_timestamp" => "0",
    "created_date"=> "2018-05-28 02:17:31",
    "created_timestamp"=> "1527445051",
    "edited_date"=> "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "edited_timestamp"=> "0",
    "updated_date"=> "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "updated_timestamp"=> "0",
    "is_complete"=> "0",
    "total_comment"=> "0",
    "total_attachment"=> "0",
    "total_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "total_completed_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "label"=> array(),
    "people"=> array(),
    "module_role"=> "author"
),array(
    "ticket_id"=> "2805",
    "ticket_title"=> "Ticket 12",
    "ticket_order"=> "1",
    "category_id"=> "827",
    "due_date"=> "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "due_timestamp"=> "0",
    "created_date"=> "2018-05-29 08:21:10",
    "created_timestamp"=> "1527553270",
    "edited_date"=> "2018-05-29 08:31:49",
    "edited_timestamp"=> "1527553909",
    "updated_date"=> "2018-05-29 08:31:49",
    "updated_timestamp"=> "1527553909",
    "is_complete"=> "0",
    "total_comment"=> "1",
    "total_attachment"=> "1",
    "total_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "total_completed_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "label"=> array(),
    "people"=> array(),
    "module_role"=> "author"
),array(
    "ticket_id"=> "3",
    "ticket_title"=> "恶徒摸索",
    "ticket_order"=> "2",
    "category_id"=> "836",
    "due_date"=> "1970-01-01 00:00:00",
    "due_timestamp"=> "0",
    "created_date"=> "2018-01-31 09:24:40",
    "created_timestamp"=> "1517361880",
    "edited_date"=> "2018-01-31 10:26:19",
    "edited_timestamp"=> "1517365579",
    "updated_date"=> "2018-01-31 10:26:19",
    "updated_timestamp"=> "1517365579",
    "is_complete"=> "0",
    "total_comment"=> "0",
    "total_attachment"=> "0",
    "total_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "total_completed_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "label"=> array(),
    "people"=> array(),
    "module_role"=> "author"
),array(
    "ticket_id"=> "4",
    "ticket_title"=> "许很多佳迪家",
    "ticket_order"=> "3",
    "category_id"=> "836",
    "due_date"=> "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
    "due_timestamp"=> "0",
    "created_date"=> "2018-01-31 10:26:43",
    "created_timestamp"=> "1517365603",
    "edited_date"=> "2018-01-31 10:26:50",
    "edited_timestamp"=> "1517365610",
    "updated_date"=> "2018-01-31 10:26:50",
    "updated_timestamp"=> "1517365610",
    "is_complete"=> "0",
    "total_comment"=> "0",
    "total_attachment"=> "0",
    "total_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "total_completed_checklist_items"=> "0",
    "label"=> array(),
    "people"=> array(),
    "module_role"=> "author"
)                
);
```

> Label data structure

```
$label = array(array(
    "ticket_label_id"=> "272",
    "ticket_label_name"=> "",
    "ticket_color_code"=> "#FF3B30",
    "ticket_id"=> "1"
),array(
    "ticket_label_id"=> "273",
    "ticket_label_name"=> "Canvas",
    "ticket_color_code"=> "#FF7200",
    "ticket_id"=> "1"
),array(
    "ticket_label_id"=> "274",
    "ticket_label_name"=> "",
    "ticket_color_code"=> "#FFCC00",
    "ticket_id"=> "1"
),array(
    "ticket_label_id"=> "282",
    "ticket_label_name"=> "11",
    "ticket_color_code"=> "#FF3B30",
    "ticket_id"=> "4"
),array(
    "ticket_label_id"=> "283",
    "ticket_label_name"=> "22",
    "ticket_color_code"=> "#FF7200",
    "ticket_id"=> "4"
),array(
    "ticket_label_id"=> "287",
    "ticket_label_name"=> "33",
    "ticket_color_code"=> "#007AFF",
    "ticket_id"=> "4"
)
              );
```

> People data structure

```
$people = array(array(
    "user_id"=> "1",
    "user_photo"=> "1521461837035726",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "1"
),array(
    "user_id"=> "3",
    "user_photo"=> "1521776192104019",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "1"
),array(
    "user_id"=> "2",
    "user_photo"=> "1523956274471195",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "1"
),array(
    "user_id"=> "8",
    "user_photo"=> "1521523017963880",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "1"
),array(
    "user_id"=> "17",
    "user_photo"=> "",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "2"
),array(
    "user_id"=> "2",
    "user_photo"=> "1523956274471195",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "2"
),array(
    "user_id"=> "23",
    "user_photo"=> "1520409780677131",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "2805"
),array(
    "user_id"=> "10",
    "user_photo"=> "1520330897067564",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "2805"
),array(
    "user_id"=> "12",
    "user_photo"=> "1517391965854528",
    "is_owner"=> "0",
    "ticket_id"=> "3"
)
               );
```

I need these above data to multidimension array with grouping, i have write a simple foreach function to group these data together, if only 1 category will will display result as expected, but if have multiple **workspace**, it will auto addin keys, my expected result is without keys, anyone please help on this issue, thank you.

> Simple foreach function for grouping with multidimension array

```
$result=array();
foreach($workspace as $key=>$value){
    $ticketCatId = $value['ticket_category_id'];
    $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_category_id'] = $value['ticket_category_id'];
    $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_category_name'] = $value['ticket_category_name'];
    $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_category_order']  = $value['ticket_category_order'];
    $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_list']  = array();
    foreach($ticket as $subkey=>$subvalue){
        $ticketId = $subvalue['ticket_id'];
        if($subvalue['ticket_id'] && 
           $value['ticket_category_id'] === $subvalue['category_id'])
        {
            $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_list'][$subkey] = array(
                'ticket_id'                         => $subvalue['ticket_id'],
                'ticket_title'                      => $subvalue['ticket_title'],
                'ticket_order'                      => $subvalue['ticket_order'],
                'category_id'                       => $subvalue['category_id'],
                'due_date'                          => $subvalue['due_date'],
                'due_timestamp'                     => $subvalue['due_timestamp'],
                'created_date'                      => $subvalue['created_date'],
                'created_timestamp'                 => $subvalue['created_timestamp'],
                'edited_date'                       => $subvalue['edited_date'],
                'edited_timestamp'                  => $subvalue['edited_timestamp'],
                'updated_date'                      => $subvalue['updated_date'],
                'updated_timestamp'                 => $subvalue['updated_timestamp'],
                'is_complete'                       => $subvalue['is_complete'],
                'total_comment'                     => $subvalue['total_comment'],
                'total_attachment'                  => $subvalue['total_attachment'],
                'total_checklist_items'             => $subvalue['total_checklist_items'],
                'total_completed_checklist_items'   => $subvalue['total_completed_checklist_items'],
                'label'                             => array(),
                'people'                            => array(),
                'module_role'                       => $subvalue['module_role'],
            );
        }

        foreach($label as $thirdkey=>$thirdvalue){
                    if($thirdvalue['ticket_id'] && 
                       $value['ticket_category_id'] === $subvalue['category_id'] &&
                       $subvalue['ticket_id'] === $thirdvalue['ticket_id'])
                    {
                        $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_list'][$subkey]['label'][] = array(
                            'ticket_label_id' => $thirdvalue['ticket_label_id'],
                            'ticket_label_name' => $thirdvalue['ticket_label_name'],
                            'ticket_color_code' => $thirdvalue['ticket_color_code'],
                            'ticket_id' => $thirdvalue['ticket_id'],
                        );
                    } 
                }
        foreach($people as $fourkey=>$fourvalue){
                    if($fourvalue['user_id'] &&
                       $value['ticket_category_id'] === $subvalue['category_id'] && 
                       $subvalue['ticket_id'] === $fourvalue['ticket_id'])
                    {
                        $result[$ticketCatId]['ticket_list'][$subkey]['people'][] = array(
                            'user_id' => $fourvalue['user_id'],
                            'user_photo' => $fourvalue['user_photo'],
                            'is_owner' => $fourvalue['is_owner'],
                            'ticket_id' => $fourvalue['ticket_id'],
                        );  
                    }
                }
    }
    $final = array_values($result);
}
var_dump(json_encode($final));
```

> below is the result i generate but is not expected

```
[{"ticket_category_id":"825",
          "ticket_category_name":" Category 1",
          "ticket_category_order":"1",
          "ticket_list":[]
         },
         {"ticket_category_id":"826",
          "ticket_category_name":"testing category for intermediate hub",
          "ticket_category_order":"1",
          "ticket_list":[
              {"ticket_id":"1",
               "ticket_title":"Fun",
               "ticket_order":"1",
               "category_id":"826",
               "due_date":"2019-04-14 06:32:37",
               "due_timestamp":"1555194757",
               "created_date":"2018-01-31 07:11:10",
               "created_timestamp":"1517353870",
               "edited_date":"2018-04-10 02:40:54",
               "edited_timestamp":"1523299254",
               "updated_date":"2018-04-10 02:40:54",
               "updated_timestamp":"1523299254",
               "is_complete":"0",
               "total_comment":"0","total_attachment":"0",
               "total_checklist_items":"0",
               "total_completed_checklist_items":"0",
               "label":[
                   {"ticket_label_id":"272",
                    "ticket_label_name":"",
                    "ticket_color_code":"#FF3B30",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"ticket_label_id":"273",
                    "ticket_label_name":"Canvas",
                    "ticket_color_code":"#FF7200",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"ticket_label_id":"274",
                    "ticket_label_name":"",
                    "ticket_color_code":"#FFCC00",
                    "ticket_id":"1"}
                ],
               "people":[
                   {"user_id":"1",
                    "user_photo":"1521461837035726",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"user_id":"3",
                    "user_photo":"1521776192104019",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"user_id":"2",
                    "user_photo":"1523956274471195",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"user_id":"8",
                    "user_photo":"1521523017963880",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   }
                ],
               "module_role":"author"
              },
              {"ticket_id":"2",
               "ticket_title":"out\u6478\u7d22",
               "ticket_order":"1",
               "category_id":"826",
               "due_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
               "due_timestamp":"0",
               "created_date":"2018-01-31 09:24:24",
               "created_timestamp":"1517361864",
               "edited_date":"2018-01-31 09:24:31",
               "edited_timestamp":"1517361871",
               "updated_date":"2018-01-31 09:24:31",
               "updated_timestamp":"1517361871",
               "is_complete":"0",
               "total_comment":"0",
               "total_attachment":"0",
               "total_checklist_items":"0",
               "total_completed_checklist_items":"0",
               "label":[],
               "people":[
                   {"user_id":"17",
                    "user_photo":"",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"2"
                   },
                   {"user_id":"2",
                    "user_photo":"1523956274471195",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"2"
                   }
                ],
               "module_role":"author"
            }
        ]
    },
    {"ticket_category_id":"827",
     "ticket_category_name":"testing category for intermediate hub",
     "ticket_category_order":"1",
     "ticket_list":
         {"2":
            {"ticket_id":"2804",
             "ticket_title":"asdas",
             "ticket_order":"6",
             "category_id":"827",
             "due_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
             "due_timestamp":"0",
             "created_date":"2018-05-28 02:17:31",
             "created_timestamp":"1527445051",
             "edited_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
             "edited_timestamp":"0",
             "updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
             "updated_timestamp":"0",
             "is_complete":"0",
             "total_comment":"0",
             "total_attachment":"0",
             "total_checklist_items":"0",
             "total_completed_checklist_items":"0",
             "label":[],
             "people":[],
             "module_role":"author"
        },
         "3":
             {"ticket_id":"2805",
              "ticket_title":"Ticket 12",
              "ticket_order":"1",
              "category_id":"827",
              "due_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
              "due_timestamp":"0",
              "created_date":"2018-05-29 08:21:10",
              "created_timestamp":"1527553270",
              "edited_date":"2018-05-29 08:31:49",
              "edited_timestamp":"1527553909",
              "updated_date":"2018-05-29 08:31:49",
              "updated_timestamp":"1527553909",
              "is_complete":"0",
              "total_comment":"1",
              "total_attachment":"1",
              "total_checklist_items":"0",
              "total_completed_checklist_items":"0",
              "label":[],
              "people":[
                  {"user_id":"23",
                   "user_photo":"1520409780677131",
                   "is_owner":"0",
                   "ticket_id":"2805"
                  },
                  {"user_id":"10",
                   "user_photo":"1520330897067564",
                   "is_owner":"0",
                   "ticket_id":"2805"
                  }
                ],
              "module_role":"author"
            }
        }
    }
```

> **This is what the result I am expected**

```
        [{"ticket_category_id":"825",
          "ticket_category_name":" Category 1",
          "ticket_category_order":"1",
          "ticket_list":[]
         },
         {"ticket_category_id":"826",
          "ticket_category_name":"testing category for intermediate hub",
          "ticket_category_order":"1",
          "ticket_list":[
              {"ticket_id":"1",
               "ticket_title":"Fun",
               "ticket_order":"1",
               "category_id":"826",
               "due_date":"2019-04-14 06:32:37",
               "due_timestamp":"1555194757",
               "created_date":"2018-01-31 07:11:10",
               "created_timestamp":"1517353870",
               "edited_date":"2018-04-10 02:40:54",
               "edited_timestamp":"1523299254",
               "updated_date":"2018-04-10 02:40:54",
               "updated_timestamp":"1523299254",
               "is_complete":"0",
               "total_comment":"0","total_attachment":"0",
               "total_checklist_items":"0",
               "total_completed_checklist_items":"0",
               "label":[
                   {"ticket_label_id":"272",
                    "ticket_label_name":"",
                    "ticket_color_code":"#FF3B30",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"ticket_label_id":"273",
                    "ticket_label_name":"Canvas",
                    "ticket_color_code":"#FF7200",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"ticket_label_id":"274",
                    "ticket_label_name":"",
                    "ticket_color_code":"#FFCC00",
                    "ticket_id":"1"}
                ],
               "people":[
                   {"user_id":"1",
                    "user_photo":"1521461837035726",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"user_id":"3",
                    "user_photo":"1521776192104019",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"user_id":"2",
                    "user_photo":"1523956274471195",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   },
                   {"user_id":"8",
                    "user_photo":"1521523017963880",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"1"
                   }
                ],
               "module_role":"author"
              },
              {"ticket_id":"2",
               "ticket_title":"out\u6478\u7d22",
               "ticket_order":"1",
               "category_id":"826",
               "due_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
               "due_timestamp":"0",
               "created_date":"2018-01-31 09:24:24",
               "created_timestamp":"1517361864",
               "edited_date":"2018-01-31 09:24:31",
               "edited_timestamp":"1517361871",
               "updated_date":"2018-01-31 09:24:31",
               "updated_timestamp":"1517361871",
               "is_complete":"0",
               "total_comment":"0",
               "total_attachment":"0",
               "total_checklist_items":"0",
               "total_completed_checklist_items":"0",
               "label":[],
               "people":[
                   {"user_id":"17",
                    "user_photo":"",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"2"
                   },
                   {"user_id":"2",
                    "user_photo":"1523956274471195",
                    "is_owner":"0",
                    "ticket_id":"2"
                   }
                ],
               "module_role":"author"
            }
        ]
    },
    {"ticket_category_id":"827",
     "ticket_category_name":"testing category for intermediate hub",
     "ticket_category_order":"1",
     "ticket_list":[
            {"ticket_id":"2804",
             "ticket_title":"asdas",
             "ticket_order":"6",
             "category_id":"827",
             "due_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
             "due_timestamp":"0",
             "created_date":"2018-05-28 02:17:31",
             "created_timestamp":"1527445051",
             "edited_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
             "edited_timestamp":"0",
             "updated_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
             "updated_timestamp":"0",
             "is_complete":"0",
             "total_comment":"0",
             "total_attachment":"0",
             "total_checklist_items":"0",
             "total_completed_checklist_items":"0",
             "label":[],
             "people":[],
             "module_role":"author"
            },
             {"ticket_id":"2805",
              "ticket_title":"Ticket 12",
              "ticket_order":"1",
              "category_id":"827",
              "due_date":"0000-00-00 00:00:00",
              "due_timestamp":"0",
              "created_date":"2018-05-29 08:21:10",
              "created_timestamp":"1527553270",
              "edited_date":"2018-05-29 08:31:49",
              "edited_timestamp":"1527553909",
              "updated_date":"2018-05-29 08:31:49",
              "updated_timestamp":"1527553909",
              "is_complete":"0",
              "total_comment":"1",
              "total_attachment":"1",
              "total_checklist_items":"0",
              "total_completed_checklist_items":"0",
              "label":[],
              "people":[
                  {"user_id":"23",
                   "user_photo":"1520409780677131",
                   "is_owner":"0",
                   "ticket_id":"2805"
                  },
                  {"user_id":"10",
                   "user_photo":"1520330897067564",
                   "is_owner":"0",
                   "ticket_id":"2805"
                  }
                ],
              "module_role":"author"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Anyone have any solutions?